# Android WebSocket connection closed due to 426 error

Tags: android, websocket, autobahn

For the last few days, I have been trying to implement WebSocket Client in my Android app. The server side user Ratchet and the configuration is ok there. The chat system works flawlessly on the web side. Now, I have tried numerous WebSocket Client Libraries like [Autobahn](https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-java), [Java-WebSocket](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket), [Tinder Scarlet](https://github.com/Tinder/Scarlet) thinking of that this is an issue on the Client side.

But every-time, when I am trying to connect to the socket endpoint, the error is :

> SocketServices Connection closed Server error 426 (No
>   Sec-WebSocket-Protocols requested supported)

Or something similar indicating that the error is 426.

My current client side code with Autobahn is:

```
 WebSocketConnection connection = new WebSocketConnection();
    try {
        connection.connect(AppConfig.WEB_SOCKET_SERVER_URI, new WebSocketConnectionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onConnect(ConnectionResponse response) {
                DebugLogger.i(TAG + "Connected to server");
            }

            @Override
            public void onOpen() {
                DebugLogger.i(TAG + "Autobahn Echo ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onClose(int code, String reason) {
                DebugLogger.i(TAG + "Connection closed " + reason);
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(String payload) {
                DebugLogger.i(TAG + "Received Message " + payload);
                connection.sendMessage(payload);
            }
        });
    } catch (WebSocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My question is if it's not a client side issue, then where should I start digging the issue from?